# DEBUG: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, jvm

I encountered a `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` when running a program.

[This link](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/738b7897-cd38-4f24-9f05-48dd69116837/entry/debugging_java_lang_nosuchmethoderror?lang=en) explained the error very clearly.

I am trying to debug this exception in Eclipse Kepler. The link recommends setting the JVM options `-Dibm.cl.verbose=[class name]`, and `-verbose:dynload`.

I set these options under Run As -> Run Configurations -> Arguments -> VM arguments.
However, after setting the options the JVM is not outputting any additional debug information.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: [package].Argument.getConsole()Lcom/beust/jcommander/internal/Console;
```

Why is the JVM not outputting the expected debug information?

Comment: Usually you get this error when you have mismatched jar files -- two jars where one depends on the other, but the depended-upon jar is the wrong version.  You can also get this when you fail to recompile all of your project, or, in some odd cases, when you're using an abstract class.

Comment: If "package" above is your package then you probably simply need to force a recompile of everything.

Comment: I tried force recompiling, still same result. Also, in Java Build Path I only have JRE System Library [JavaSE-1.7] and Maven Dependencies in there. Any other possibilities you know of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED]

So it was a conflict with some dependency issue. Basically I had Maven version 1.17 and 1.30 somehow. I deleted the older one and the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

According to the code on this page : https://github.com/cbeust/jcommander/blob/master/src/main/java/com/beust/jcommander/WrappedParameter.java

Jcommander can throw a NoSuchMethodException itself if you've led it to expect a list (that should have a 'put' method) but give it a type that doesn't have that method.